# Interprocess communication, kinda tricky?

Tags: c#, wpf, ipc

I need to send a short string from a NON-ELEVATED console app to an ELEVATED WPF app. So pipes won't work, since I can't get a safe handle (due to elevation). WM_ messages are super annoying, especially with wpf (at least from what I've found online). So what's the best solution?! I don't need to communicate back. I don't need any safe connection. I really just need to send a small string without a big fuzz. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps throwing a localhost UDP packet might be useful? Have one process listen on a port, have the other one send it packet/s.

Comment: You can use an EventWaitHandle + a MemoryMap

Answer (score 0):

Hava a look at [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) . CodeProject has a [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138290/Programming-Memory-Mapped-Files-with-the-NET-Frame) on it.

Answer (score 0):

WCF can cross elevation, it is only a trivial amount of setup to get a server running in process. I also beleive it's NamedPipeEndpoint allows for elevation crossing. See this simple tutorial to set it up https://web.archive.org/web/20141027055124/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication